# SharePoint App Deployment error : 'Failed to install app for SharePoint'

Tags: 2013, deployment, sharepoint-addin

I created a test MVC sharepoint app succesfully in a solution.
Now I need to integrate this into a main solution project.

But when I added a SharePoint MVC App into the solution and hit F5, I am getting following error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': 
Failed to install app for SharePoint. Please see the output window for details.
```

Detailed stack trace:

```
CorrelationId: 50583239-71cb-4b07-8bcb-4bbc51a22631
     ErrorDetail: There was a problem with activating the app web definition.
     ErrorType: App
     ErrorTypeName: App Related
     ExceptionMessage: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(Guid featureId, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.Add(Guid featureId, Boolean force, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.EnsureWebFeaturesActivated(SPUserSolution solution)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.ActivateSolution(SPWeb web, SPUserSolution solution)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.Deploy()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTask()
     Source: AppWeb
     SourceName: App Web Deployment
```

Can somebody shed a light on this issue? :)

Comment: Could you add more detail pertaining to what you have tried or how you got to this point?

Comment: creating app is fine in new solution. But when I tried to add into an existing solution, it is showing the above error. What information you need more?

Comment: Try to set name of your MVC project as the project which is created by default for web. It looks like the project names depends on each other.

Comment: It is default only. I haven't changed it